# Best way to return value from serial port within a library

Tags: c#, .net, dll, serial-port

I am trying to send and receive data by serial port, and I can get data from DataReceived event normally.
Now, I make a library, which is developed to send and receive data by serial port. I don't know how to send command and retrieve value by two different methods.
It makes me confused, help me, please!

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        FXReader reader = new FXReader();
        reader.ComPort = port;
        reader.Connect();

        Console.WriteLine(reader.SetPortPower(1));
        Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine(reader.GetPortStatus(1));
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

public class FXReader : IDisposable
{
    private SerialPort rs232 = null;

    public string ComPort
    {
        get { return rs232.PortName; }
        set { rs232.PortName = value; }
    }

    public bool IsConnected
    {
        get { return rs232.IsOpen; }
    }

    public F520Reader()
    {
        rs232 = new SerialPort();
        rs232.BaudRate = 115200;            
        rs232.Parity = Parity.None;
        rs232.DataBits = 8;
        rs232.StopBits = StopBits.One;
        rs232.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(rs232_DataReceived);
    }

    public void Connect()
    {
        rs232.Open();
    }

    public void Disconnect()
    {
        rs232.Close();
    }

    public int GetPortPower(int port)
    {
        if (rs232.IsOpen)
        {
            byte[] command = { 0x5A, 0x00, 0x19, 0x00, 0x01, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x7E };
            rs232.Write(command, 0, command.Length);

            //How can i get value from the event of "rs232_DataReceived"
            return powervalue;
        }
    }

    public int GetPortStatus(int port)
    {
        if (rs232.IsOpen)
        {
            byte[] command = { 0x5A, 0x00, 0x19, 0x00, 0x01, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x7E };
            rs232.Write(command, 0, command.Length);

            //How can i get value from the event of "rs232_DataReceived"
            return statusvalue;
        }
    }

    void rs232_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(50);
        if (rs232.BytesToRead > 0)
        {
            byte[] recvBuffer = new byte[1024];
            int recvLength = rs232.Read(recvBuffer, 0, recvBuffer.Length);
            Array.Resize(ref recvBuffer, recvLength);

            PharseResponse(recvBuffer);
        }
    }

    private void PharseResponse(byte[] buffer)
    {
        if (buffer[0] == 0x5A && buffer[buffer.Length - 1] == 0x7E)
        {
            #region Response for Get Port Power
            if (buffer[1] == 0x01 && buffer[2] == 0x13)
            {
                //How can I return value by the method of "GetPortPower"
                return buffer[7];
            }
            #endregion

            #region Response for Get Port Status
            if (buffer[1] == 0x01 && buffer[2] == 0x14)
            {
                //How can I return value by the method of "GetPortStatus"
                return buffer[7];
            }
            #endregion
        }
    }       

    #region IDisposable Members

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (rs232.IsOpen)
            rs232.Close();

        rs232.Dispose();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: What is this device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is certainly not the "best way".  You are not getting any benefit whatsoever from using the DataReceived event.  It is useful in an event-driven application, a GUI app for example.  But not in app like this where you must get a response before you can proceed in your program.

So don't use it at all, call the Read() method directly instead.  Your program will block until the device sends something back.

Which will also help you write correct code, it is not correct right now.  Reading from a serial port normally produces only one or two bytes.  The return value of Read() tells you how many you got.  You cannot parse the response until you got a *complete* one.  It isn't very obvious from your current code what "complete" looks like, but you need to have received at least 8 bytes before your PharseResponse() method will stop crashing with an IndexOutOfRangeException. A serial protocol often uses a specific byte value to indicate the end of the response.